# Turn comment into answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, convert-to-answer

When I get the best answer to my question in a comment, is it possible to convert this comment into an answer, and accept it? Sometimes the poster don't bother to do the conversion, which is a problem because I would like to accept the best answer.

Comment: What acceptance ratio? We got rid of that nonsense, didn't we?

Comment: I haven't realized that, thanks :) I will modify the question.

Comment: The generally accepted process is to: Ask the commenter to write an answer. If, after some time as passed the commenter hasn't done so, go ahead and write the answer yourself with the information and accept it. It's generally considered good form to give credit to the commenter and to mark the answer as Community Wiki, so you don't get any reputation points from it.

Comment: "[Downvotes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)". More than likely people are expressing their opinion about your feature request, not on your question's suitability.

Comment: @AlEverett I don't consider CW a good practice when stealing someone's comments and posting them as answers. First it's not what CW is for (it's only meant to encourage edits) and second _most_ comments would require at least some effort to stand as answers. If you put the effort, you deserve the rep, if you don't, you should be downvoted and lose rep.

Comment: @Yannis: I don't necessarily disagree, but that is what I have seen suggested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to convert a comment to an answer, and it's not really a good idea either.

If I choose to post an answer as a comment you can assume that I don't feel it stands as an answer, at least not an answer that I want posted under my name. If you disagree and feel the comment is a good enough answer, feel free to post it as an answer yourself, that's perfectly fine and even encouraged.

Comment: Worth to mention that the other way around is possible for moderators.

Comment: Also, very short answers are automatically converted to comments @ShaWizDowArd (not sure on the exact criteria). But answer-to-comment is not the same as comment-to-answer, we have a high set of standards for answers (and also it's quite common for users with less than 50 rep to post helpful comments as answers because they can't comment yet, which is probably why the answer-to-comment mod feature exists in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

If you feel a comment is the answer to your question then you can ask the commentor to write one in order to accept it. Most users will do that because everyone likes a little reputation.

But if not then you could write an answer yourself. But don't just copy a comment into an answer. An answer should not just be a one-liner. It should explain the matter.

An automatism to convert comments into answers is not the way to go. That would not meet our quality standards for answers on SE.